# Problems with PHP associative array and MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, null, associative-array

I recently added a new column to a MySQL database (featured), then added that column into my associative array. Rather than calling the data for the new column, I simply get 'null' in place of each entry, even after specifically requesting the column to be 'not null'.

I thought I may have been calling the data incorrectly, however, my array seems fine:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($blogs, array('title' => $row['title'], 'content' => $row['content'], 'featured' => $row['featured']));
}
```

And this is the response I get:

```
{"blogs":[{"title":"test-title","content":"test-content","featured":null}]}
```

I'm guessing this must be a MySQL issue, but I've no idea what it could be.

Comment: You might have not updated this new column for older entries.Have yu checked this?

Comment: Yes, I've applied all changes within MySQL, if that's what you mean?

Comment: No i mean check the row,if you have added a value corresponding to this new column in your table.Older records would not have any value for 'featued' initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the SQL query executed doesn't select this new column, or uses another name as the one you're expecting:

```
select title, content from ...
```

or

```
select title, content, feature as f from ...
```

Comment: Oh my God, I feel so dumb. Of course that was the issue. I'd simply misspelled `featured` as `feature`.

Comment: Sorry for wasting everybody's time.

Comment: A friendly reminder that next time you should consult your rubber duck first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score -2):

You're using `$row['...']` instead of `$result['...']`

Comment: I thought this initially but if I use `$result['...']` instead of `$row['...']` then `null` is still returned.